# Objective C, hand code application forms? Possible?

Tags: objective-c, user-interface

so I am learning Objective C, and using Mac Xcode compiler. Coming from Java I was used to Hand coding my JFrames rather than using the form editor. I like the editor in Xcode and all, but was wondering if there was a way to hand code buttons and text boxes on to an application "Form"? What kind of project to start with? Would you start with some kind of FormClass? and if so, how would set up the interface.header.

Comment: There's no concept of a form in cocoa - you have views. Are you discussing cocoa here, or maybe another UI framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no concept of a Form in Objective C. As mentioned in the comment to your question, its about View Controllers/Views here.

Yes it is possible to hand code buttons and text boxes. You need to do that in the implementation file of your class. I am assuming that you know what are the .h and .m of Objective C.

So, to code a button, you'd write something like this:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button addTarget:self 
         action:@selector(aMethod:)  //Method you want to call when a user taps your button
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[button setTitle:@"Sample Button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 160.0, 40.0);
[view addSubview:button];
```

Eventually, after coding your button, you add it as a subview to your main view. Note that Objective C supports nested views. So you can add a view inside your view that further contains a subview.

Comment: Alright! So because there is no Window or Form concept, I would have to start with Application project then add controls at runtime... Just a bit different style to get used to. Thanks for the help!!!!!

Comment: Yeah..Many use the Interface Builder/Storyboard to design the view..But it's completely fine to do that with code. Glad I could help.

Comment: I recommend doing as much as you can visually--it will be much easier for you to edit.